# User authentication SQL injection

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql

Is this authentication mechanism vulnerable to SQL injection?
If so, how could one exploit it, and what is the most effective way to mitigate this?

```
if (isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

$username = $_POST['userid'];
$password = crypt($_POST['password'],'34l5kj');


    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name =:username and pass=:password";
$db->query($query);
$db->bind(':username', $username);
$db->bind(':password', $password);
$db->execute();
$data = $db->single();

            $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $data['id'];
            $_SESSION['pwd']=$_POST['password'];
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but we do not do code reviews here.

Comment: You can always post this in code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  There is actually quite a lot to unpack in this short bit of code.  If you re-post this on codereview and ping me in a comment here, I would be happy to share my thoughts.

Comment: @ConorMancone It seems I can't tag you in the new post.
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178549/user-authentication-sql-injection

Comment: Oh, you said here.

Answer (score 3):

You are using bound params which is a great start. This tiny snippet of code *should* be fine against regular input SQLi but there are a few other potential issues:

- You are not validating/sanitising the input. Although your are using bind, you should still be doing this
- You are assigning the password to a session variable. Why? You effectively have the plain text PW floating around your web app
- You are not sanitising the DB output before storing it in the SESSION variables. Not knowing what your other code looks it is impossible to see how this would be exploited. Just don't take the chance.